# React select multi select one option not clearable

Tags: reactjs, select, input, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://react-select.com/) in my project. I have it for multiple select and it looks like this:

[image]

and it works fine. The problem is I would like to have one option already selected and it would be not clearable so it will not have "X" near it

[image]

I just need it for one option, all others have to be normally in the options and clearable.
How can I achieve that? Is it a special prop added to options or can I check them some way that if option name is `commercial` it will not have possibility to clear and would be selected on initial

Answer (score 4):

`react-select` has a [fixed options](https://react-select.com/home#fixed-options) example on the docs but I found this solution is much cleaner. You can remove `MultiValueRemove` component (the delete button) based on the option value:

```
const MultiValueRemove = (props) => {
  if (props.data.isFixed) {
    return null;
  }
  return <components.MultiValueRemove {...props} />;
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <Select
      isMulti
      defaultValue={[colourOptions[0], colourOptions[1]]}
      isClearable={false}
      options={colourOptions}
      components={{ MultiValueRemove }}
    />
  );
};
```

The select above will remove the delete button of any option that has the `isFixed` property set to `true` (the first 2 options below).

```
export const colourOptions = [
  { value: 'ocean', label: 'Ocean', color: '#00B8D9', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'red', label: 'Red', color: '#FF5630', isFixed: true },
  { value: 'purple', label: 'Purple', color: '#5243AA' },
  { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange', color: '#FF8B00' },
  { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow', color: '#FFC400' },
  { value: 'green', label: 'Green', color: '#36B37E' },
  { value: 'forest', label: 'Forest', color: '#00875A' },
  { value: 'slate', label: 'Slate', color: '#253858' },
  { value: 'silver', label: 'Silver', color: '#666666' },
];
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67302509/react-select-multi-select-one-option-not-clearable]

Comment: Thing with unclearable option is working but I have problem with setting defaultValue, it is not beeing set like defaultValue prop is not working, I have function that creates options so I pass the same function to defaultValue and of course take first element of it by [0] but it is not working as expected, no values are set on initial

Comment: @Sowam can you fork my codesandbox to make a reproducible example. You also need to add your `defaultValue` code to the question so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that by using `isClearable` props of react-select like below

Consider your options array have `fixed` boolean set to true

```
<Select
  // other props
  isClearable={options.some(v => !v.isFixed)}
/>
```

And you can change you `multiValueRemove` in styles const like this

```
const styles = {

  // other styles here

  multiValueRemove: (base, state) => {
    return state.data.isFixed ? { ...base, display: 'none' } : base;
  },
};
```

You can find more info in `Fixed option` section of https://react-select.com/home#fixed-options

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export const CreatingSelect: FC<CreatingSelectProps> = (props) => {
    const { className, components, ...restProps } = props;
    const selectClassName = cn('select', className);

    const MultiValueRemove = (props: PropsWithChildren<any>) => {
        return (
            <div className={props.innerProps.className} onClick={props.innerProps.onClick}>
                <SvgIcon name={iconNames.cross} />
            </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        <SelectStyled
            styles={customStyles}
            className={selectClassName}
            classNamePrefix='select'
            components={{ ...components, MultiValueRemove }}
            {...restProps}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: Please add some text to support your code